# passing InputStream to a different class and getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an InputStream inside my activity.  It creates just fine but I am trying to pass the created InputStream to a class where I actually want to work with the InputStream.   The InputStream in created inside an onClick method on my activity.  The second I try to pass the InputStream object to a method inside my "working class" I get a NullPointerException.  I do not want to do the work inside my activity.  How can I pass either the InputStream or even an AssetManager object to work with it.  My "working class" doesnt extend or implement anything.  Should it?

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        private DbManagement mdbManager;
        private TestProcessor tp;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lookup);
            mdbManager = new DbManagement(this);
            mdbManager.open();
            fillData();
            Button testingCsv =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTestCsv);
            testingCsv.setOnClickListener(ChokeSlam);
            testPopulate_Tests();

        }

        private OnClickListener ChokeSlam = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AssetManager aM = getAssets();
                InputStream ipNext = null;
                InputStreamReader iprNext = null;
                try{                
                    //ipNext = aM.open("Book1.csv");
                    //CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(ipNext));
                    //iprNext = new InputStreamReader(ipNext);
                    //tp.ProcessInboundStream(ipNext);
                    tp.ProcessInboundStream(aM,"Book1.csv");
                    ipNext.close();
                    //tp.ProcessInboundStream(new InputStream(ipNext));
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                  System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }

        };



    public class TestProcessor {
        private DbManagement mdbManager;
        private final Context mctx;

        public TestProcessor(Context ctx) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mctx = ctx;
        }
        public void ProcessInboundStream(AssetManager aM,String fileName){


            InputStream ipNext = null;
            try{                
                ipNext = aM.open(fileName);
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(ipNext));        
                ipNext.close();
                //tp.ProcessInboundStream(new InputStream(ipNext));
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
              System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This description is not enough, add the code.

Comment: If you want to pass objects to another activity, you need to use `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

Comment: It isnt to another activity it is to a class that I want to use to actually process the data

Comment: Where is the crash log?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. BTW where do you allocate memory for TestProcessor? My guess the problem is in this line `tp.ProcessInboundStream(aM,"Book1.csv")` coz I don't see any TestProcessor instantiation in the code that you have posted.

Comment: THank you guys.  I figured it out but you guys can probably tell by the code that I never correct instantiated the tp object.  All I did was declare the object.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted much to go on. In your line:

```
ipNext = aM.open(fileName);
```

are you certain the AssetManager `am` is not `null` at this point? It seems to be only initialised in a remote `onClick` method. I can't tell when you're instantiating a `TestProcess`.

Failing that, check:

```
ipNext = aM.open(fileName);
```

and make sure `ipNext` is not `null`. Perhaps the file is not found, so a `null` stream is returned.

Anyway, the crash log will tell you the line on which your NPE is occurring. From there you can resolve this yourself quite quickly.

Comment: I have included more code above to show where the tp object is instantiated.

Comment: THank you guys.  I figured it out but you guys can probably tell by the code that I never correct instantiated the tp object.  All I did was declare the object.

Answer (score 0):

THank you guys.  I figured it out but you guys can probably tell by the code that I never correct instantiated the tp object.  All I did was declare the object. I added this line of code to the onCreate method.

```
    tp = new TestProcessor(this);
```